# Bracing a polygon without triangles

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, coloring, rigid-transformation

The following [Laman graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LamanGraph.html) braces a square without triangles. Stated another way, this is a unit-distance rigid graph without 3-cycles. It seems to be the smallest example of a triangle-free [braced polygon](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BracedPolygon.html).  This happens to be a subgraph of the [unit sticks cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675079/doubling-the-cube-with-unit-sticks/2686088#2686088) graph.

[image: braced square]

What other regular polygons have triangle-free rigid constructions?

Comment: Do you have a reference? Clearly, a lot of work has gone into these.

Comment: Ummm.... how do you know these brace a hexagon?  Just drawing them doesn't show it.

Comment: I get that the H-O-Fish graph is *not* infinitesimally rigid, but it might be finitely rigid. 
Also, the vertices I get from Mathematica 12.1.0 with GraphData[g,"VertexCoordinates"]] for O-Graph40 aren't unit distance.  Is there a different embedding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Any rigid framework, hence all regular polygons, can be converted to a triangle-free equivalent.** Simply chaining copies of the $12$-vertex triangle-free braced square shown in the question (which I discovered) along the two collinear edges gives a rigid line segment of arbitrary whole number length without triangles:

[image]

Then any triangular grid can be mimicked without triangles as follows (all straight fuchsia edges are made with the graph chaining construction above, all black edges are single sticks):

[image]

For example, to brace the hexagon without triangles:

[image]

---

However, the above hexagon bracing is quite big. Another approach to triangle-free bracing is the *virtual edge*: in any embedding of the cubical graph with one edge removed, the distance between the two degree-$2$ vertices (incident to the missing edge) must always be $1$. This leads to the following triangle-free rigid regular hexagon in $16$ vertices and $29$ edges ([Shibuya commit proof](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya/commit/dd4377764ad564a8abd8bee63c7dc28a68a601d8)):

[image]

[image]

The two versions shown above are graph-theoretically isomorphic; their coordinates have the same minimal polynomials. In particular, using the parametrisation in Shibuya, the $x$-coordinate of vertex $7$ satisfies
$$12x^2-6(\alpha+2)x+(\alpha^2+4\alpha+1)=0,\ \alpha=\sqrt[3]3$$
$$(864x^6-2592x^5+2808x^4-1296x^3+342x^2-207x+83=0)$$
([Thanks Hulpke](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050430/357390) for pointing me to the GAP function `DecomPoly` that allowed me to get the first polynomial.) The faint lines in the second version show that the rigid graph is related to the order-$4$ hypercube graph.

Comment: Brilliant.  And it seems this is actually the first polygon braced without triangles.

Comment: "There are coincident vertices in the final graph, but no triangles."  You can do it without coincident vertices.  Take a normal hexagon bracing, braced on the outside, and scale it up to size 2.  Then add the size 1 hexagon at the center.  Similarly, scale up a square bracing to size 3.

Comment: @EdPegg I came up with that exact graph too. Did you cheat and look at [my Shibuya repo](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya/commit/1a646cd4e65e60ba34c3fdd689a501561e75c763)? I am going to publish this.

Comment: Came from you, William Somsky and Eric Weisstein, actually.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BracedPolygon.html  Came from you via the graph I posted to your cube sticks question, and I took another look.

Comment: Looks like you found the 12 vertex square bracing 10 hours before I found it independently based on a William Somsky 13 vertex graph and program, when I asked him to look at cube-sticks graph.

Comment: @EdPegg The commit into Shibuya that introduced the $12$-vertex braced square is [here](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya/commit/2e3138928ea3a6b15d70c01447530da056a9558b) (3 January 22:13 UTC+8). I was trying to find the smallest rigid triangle-free unit-distance graph, not necessarily containing a square. Is the braced square optimal in that sense or is there something smaller? There are no such graphs on $9$ or fewer vertices.

Comment: Smallest rigid triangle-free unit-distance graph? Good question.  Answer; it will come from an algebraic space with a relatively small discriminant.  I don't know which discriminant, though.  The 3D question is also interesting.

Comment: I believe you can drop one edge of your hexagon graph (the one not part of the two reduced-cube graphs) and you end up with a flexible over-all triangle-free graph that still braces the hexagon rigidly!

Comment: According to Somsky, " if you drop the 4-13 edge from the hexagon graph, you get a curious entity. I believe the resulting graph is not rigid itself as a whole, but the hexagon will be rigid!"

Comment: @EdPegg This is to be expected. You can drop the 8-9 edge too and the hexagon is still rigid.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Side query from a brony: As the _Princess of Science_ per your profile, do you prefer your _Nom-de-Net_, ParclyTaxel, to be referred to as "he" or "she"?

Comment: @WRSomsky I am a male in real life and should be referred to as "he". The Princess of Science moniker refers to my MLPFIM OC, also called Parcly Taxel, who is a she.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Good enough. I know some folks who use alternate pronouns for their on-line personas, so just wanted to check. "He", it is.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Parcly Taxel's answer, his hexagon bracings are a subset of a whole 2DOF family of hexagonal bracings.  Here are two especially symmetric members of this family. (The dotted lines indicate unit-separations that are not included as edges.)

[image]
[image]